# Word Count, Segmentation Fault - C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, word-count

I'm trying to run a program that finds the word count for a file. Every time I compile the program it gives me a Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped). Can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int wc = 1;
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char c = fgetc(input);
    while(c != EOF){
        if(c == ' '){
            wc++;
        }
        else
            c = fgetc(input);
    }
    fclose(input);
    printf("Word Count = %d", wc);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I compile the program it gives me a Segmentation Fault". I assume you mean when you *run* the program. So how are you running the program? Perhaps the `fopen` failed. You should always have error checking code to validate that function calls succeed.

Comment: You should also check `argc` to make sure that a file name was passed as an argument. By the way, the first time that `c` is a space you'll go into an infinite loop since you'll never read a new `c` after that. And why is `wc` set to 1 before any words are ever found?

Comment: `char c = fgetc` `fgetc` returns an `int` intentionally, not a `char`. And always check function results for errors!

Comment: To extend lurker's comment, you should use `while ((c = fgetc(input)) != EOF)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably segfaulting because you're not passing in a file name on the command line.  When you do that, `argv[1]` is NULL, so `fopen` is dereferencing a NULL pointer.

You pass the file name to your program on the command line like this:

```
./my_program file_to_test
```

To prevent the core dump, you should check that an argument was passed in by checking the value of `argc`.  You should also check the return value of `fopen` to ensure the file was opened:

```
if (argc < 2) {
    printf("no file name given");
    exit(1);
}
FILE *input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
if (input == NULL) {
    perror("fopen failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Then you have another problem:

```
    if(c == ' '){
        wc++;
    }
    else
        c = fgetc(input);
```

When you find a space character, you don't attempt to read the next character.  So `c` doesn't change once a space is read, leading to an infinite loop.

You need to get rid of the `else` and always call `fgetc`:

```
    if(c == ' '){
        wc++;
    }
    c = fgetc(input);
```

Also, the `fgetc` function returns an `int` (actually an `unsigned char` cast to an `int`), so you should declare `c` as an `int`.  Otherwise, checking it against `EOF` can fail.

Comment: One more thing: `c` should be an `int`